# How to combine multiple results?

Tags: sql

I have a query which returns the total # of tickets of assignees:

```
SELECT DISTINCT case
    when ASSIGNEE LIKE '%e474728%' then 'Jason'
    when ASSIGNEE LIKE '%e499653%' then 'Alexis'
    when ASSIGNEE LIKE '%e509255%' then 'David'
    when ASSIGNEE LIKE '%e533676%' then 'KC Lin'
    when ASSIGNEE LIKE '%Desktop_Support%' then 'LIKE Desktop Support'
    when ASSIGNEE = 'Desktop_Support' then 'Desktop Support (unknown)'
else 'ASSIGNEE UNKNOWN'

End as ASSIGNEE,

COUNT(STATUS) as tickets
FROM techsupport
WHERE STATUS = 'Closed'
AND ASSIGNEE LIKE '%Desktop_Support%'

GROUP BY ASSIGNEE
```

WHICH produces the result:

```
ASSIGNEE                    tickets

Desktop Support (unknown)   981
David                       445
Alexis                      135
Jason                       48
KC Lin                      20
ASSIGNEE UNKNOWN            19
KC Lin                      18
Alexis                      15
Alexis                      14
KC Lin                      12
David                       11
ASSIGNEE UNKNOWN            11
Alexis                      10
Alexis                      8
ASSIGNEE UNKNOWN            7
Alexis                      4
Jason                       4
ASSIGNEE UNKNOWN            4
```

How do I combine the various Assignees?

So that it shows the combined totals of each Assignee?

```
ASSIGNEE                    tickets

Desktop Support (unknown)   981
David                       456
Jason                       52
KC Lin                      50
ASSIGNEE UNKNOWN            41
Alexis                      186
```

Thanks!

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: You would have to repeat the 'case' in the group by, rather than plain assignee. Can't you manage the cases through a join at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are grouping by ASSIGNEE, not by the result of the case expression (rename is performed after group by). Also distinct is redundant, here's one way to do it without repeating the case in the group by clause:

```
SELECT ASSIGNEE, count(status)
FROM (
    SELECT case when ASSIGNEE LIKE '%e474728%' then 'Jason'
                when ASSIGNEE LIKE '%e499653%' then 'Alexis'
                when ASSIGNEE LIKE '%e509255%' then 'David'
                when ASSIGNEE LIKE '%e533676%' then 'KC'
                when ASSIGNEE LIKE '%Desktop_Support%' then 'LIKE Desktop Support'
                when ASSIGNEE = 'Desktop_Support' then 'Desktop Support (unknown)'
                else 'ASSIGNEE UNKNOWN'
           End as ASSIGNEE
         , STATUS
    FROM techsupport
    WHERE STATUS = 'Closed'
) as X 
GROUP BY ASSIGNEE;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a different name for the alias of the `case` to distinguish it from the original column name.

```
SELECT DISTINCT case
    when ASSIGNEE LIKE '%e474728%' then 'Jason'
    when ASSIGNEE LIKE '%e499653%' then 'Alexis'
    when ASSIGNEE LIKE '%e509255%' then 'David'
    when ASSIGNEE LIKE '%e533676%' then 'KC'
    when ASSIGNEE LIKE '%Desktop_Support%' then 'LIKE Desktop Support'
    when ASSIGNEE = 'Desktop_Support' then 'Desktop Support (unknown)'
else 'ASSIGNEE UNKNOWN'

End as ASSIGNEE_GRP,

COUNT(STATUS) as tickets
FROM techsupport
WHERE STATUS = 'Closed'
AND ASSIGNEE LIKE '%Desktop_Support%'

GROUP BY ASSIGNEE_GRP
```

Comment: Minor nitpick, This will not work in all DBMS since renaming of columns should be done after group by.

Answer (score 0):

Logical Processing Order of the SELECT statement:

1. FROM
2. ON
3. OUTER
4. WHERE
5. GROUP BY
6. CUBE | ROLLUP
7. HAVING
8. SELECT
9. DISTINCT
   10 ORDER BY
10. TOP

If you know this you will understand why the assignees are getting repeated.

Answer (score -3):

Try group by clause in your query. `group by assignee`